# Laravel: can't redirect to the correct page after submitting form

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

So I have an issue where i can't seem to get it to redirect to the dashboard after a user signs up by submitting their details to the database. Instead i get this message in firefox: "The page has expired due to inactivity.Please refresh and try again." and in the url it does not say /dashboard it says /signup.

This is my web.php route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('user/usersignup');
});


Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);

Route::post('/signin', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as' => 'signin'
]);

Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard'
]);
```

This is UserController, my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class UserController extends Controller
    {
       public function getDashboard(){
           return view('dashboard');
       }

       public function postSignUp(Request $request){
           $first_name = $request['first_name'];
           $email = $request['email'];
           $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

           $user= new User();
           $user->first_name = $first_name;
           $user->email = $email;
           $user->password = $password;

           $user->save();
           return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }
    }
```

This is my signup view: usersignup.blade.php

```
  <form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" id="userform">

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">Your first Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="fullname">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="password">Your Password</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
 </form>
```

Comment: What's the version of Laravel used?

Comment: I recently just got it so I think it is 5.6

Comment: Follow C2486 answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Wrong [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf).

Either use `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside `<form>` tag and remove hidden element `name="_token"`

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" id="userform">
{{ csrf_field() }}
.....
.....
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or replace value of hidden element `_token` to `csrf_token()`

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" id="userform">
.....
.....
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: I now get this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`first_name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (...), I changed fullname to first_name in the form but still got the issue.

Comment: Congratulations your previous problem is fixed. For this you need to provide value for `first_name` or you had to set default value for this column

Comment: That is the thing I type a name into the text field but it says that I have not given a value I have no idea why.

Comment: Use like this instead `$first_name = $request->first_name;` to get values from `$request`

Comment: I still get the same issue, I think that was just the different way of writing the same thing.

Comment: try first by hardcode value `$first_name = "myname";` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a csrf field to the form instead of hidden _token input:

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" id="userform">
     {{ csrf_field() }}

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname">Your Full Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="password">Your Password</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```